# How to remove a specific child node from a Group in OSGVP?

Tags: java

I have the following problem and I don't know how to resolve it.

I have a `Group` class where I have some `Nodes` and I add more nodes constantly. One of them is named `"figure"` and I would like to identify this node to remove it.

For example I have an initial Group:

1 line
2 point
3 figure

And then I add more nodes:

1 line
2 point
3 figure
4 line
5 point

I have used this but I have not got it because I can only use it in one situation:

```
pp.setNodeName("figure");

int numNodes= this._featureNodes.getNumChildren();

if (this._featureNodes.getChild(numNodes-1).getNodeName() == "figure")
{
    this._featureNodes.removeChild(numNodes-1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it!!

The solution was to create a "for" loop to read all items of my group and identify the node "figure" like this:

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i< this._featureNodes.getNumChildren(); ++i){

   if (_featureNodes.getChild(i).getNodeName().equals("figure"))
    {
        this._featureNodes.removeChild(i);  
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` for comapring Strings not `==` operator. `equals()` compares whether the `nodeName` has the same String characters. `==` compares whether two references reference the same object. Therefore, your if block would be as follows:

```
if (this._featureNodes.getChild(numNodes-1).getNodeName().equals("figure"))
{
    this._featureNodes.removeChild(numNodes-1); 
}
```

Comment: Ok!!

But with this I only can resolve the first situation A:
1 line; 2 point; 3 figure.

But what's happening when I add another node as this situation B?:
1 line; 2 point; 3 figure; 4 lineb; 5 pointb;